# Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: internet-explorer, timer, telerik

I have an asp page with Timer control. Timer control will trigger some method to execute.

When this page is loaded, following error comes and timer control is not triggered to tick.

I use IE9. 
There is no issues in FF and chrome.

Error details are as follows. Anybody have an experience with this message ?

Webpage error details

```
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Thu, 12 May 2011 12:35:10 UTC

Message: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.

Line: 6
Char: 70575
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/AbcWeb/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ctl00_RadScriptManager1_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen%3a1f68db6e-ab92-4c56-8744-13e09bf43565%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%3aen%3a183fb741-216d-4765-9b46-4a1f5d38fdd7%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3aed16cbdc%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen%3a1f68db6e-ab92-4c56-8744-13e09bf43565%3a76254418%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2010.2.929.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen%3a183fb741-216d-4765-9b46-4a1f5d38fdd7%3a874f8ea2%3a24ee1bba%3a19620875%3a490a9d4e%3abd8f85e4%3a9cdfc6e7
```

**When I debug the js. the above error is occured when adding css to the document (document.createStyleSheet(hrefs[i])).

Will it be a memory issue ?.**

```
(function() {
                    function loadHandler() {
                        var hrefs = ['/WmsWeb/Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2010.2.929.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen%3a183fb741-216d-4765-9b46-4a1f5d38fdd7%3a1c2121e' ];
                        var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
                        for (var i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++)
                            if ($telerik.isIE) document.createStyleSheet(hrefs[i]);
                            else {
                                var link = document.createElement('link');
                                link.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
                                link.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
                                link.setAttribute('href', hrefs[i]);
                                head.appendChild(link);
                            }
                        Sys.Application.remove_load(loadHandler);
                    }
                    Sys.Application.add_load(loadHandler);
                })();
```

Thank you in Advance.

DineshNS

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Finally I found the issue to get this "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation." appear on IE9.

The reason is IE9 has a limitation to have 31 css references per page. In my page has more than 31 references.

Refer following link.

http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-05-03/internet_explorer_css_limits.aspx.

To resolve this issue. I moved the all css in App_Theame to new folder. and create one css in App_Theme folder, and include "@import url("../../styles/Stylesheet01.css");" lines per each css.

Then browser will refer to only one css.

Comment: You have to be kidding me.  What a ridiculous bug. Microsoft #win

Comment: More info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906794/internet-explorers-css-rules-limits