# Magento CSS Merge breaks layout in IE browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, magento-1.4

I am developing a magento website, and it is using CSS merge option. currently in IE the CSS not rendering properly. When I remove some part of CSS file its working. Some times it works when I remove 50 line from top. Some times it works when I remove 100 lines from bottom. So it's nothing related to the CSS I wrote. Merged file contains about 6000 lines and having 380 KB file size.

can anybody help me on this ?

Thanks

Comment: hi, i have the same problem. With which ie version do you have the problem?

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906794/internet-explorers-css-rules-limits

Answer (score 0):

I added media="null" attribute to in the  node in layout.xml for the file having huge size. So it will be merged as another file along with media="all" and media="print".

This is worked for me.

Comment: NOT WORK!
if you use media="null" page not load css

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Internet Explorer's 8 and 9 4095 selectors limit.

In my case I've had a list of about 7 style-sheets that were added in page.xml(so site-wide). Total selector count in these files was 4463 so above the limit.

I've used:

```
@import 'some-style-sheet.css' all;
```

for 3 top style sheets, to import them into the 4th one, then commented out these 3 in page.xml.

That helped as the total number of selectors in the merged file was reduced.