# CSS not loading on ie7 or earlier

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm having an issue in ie7 where my stylesheet isn't loading at all, I've checked that it's encoded as utf-8 without BOM and the charset on the page is set as utf-8.  Here's the head:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/themes/dark/less/style.css">

        <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

And here's the site if it's any help: http://www.mattjonesmusic.com/

I think this bug likely occurs on ie6 as well although I don't have a vm setup to test it.

Comment: is the stylesheet not loaded or just the rules not applied? Have you seen some error with an HTTP sniffer?

Comment: Looking at it, it seems to load the stylesheet, but only down to the .progress section.  All of that section is from twitter's bootstrap styles.

Comment: Have you hit the CSS limit?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906794/internet-explorers-css-rules-limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, it was a compilation issue (I'm compiling bootstrap myself from source).  I'd got rid of an include defining a variable that was used only in ie filters.

Thanks to all that tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing the following tag meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"