# Bootstrap3 col-md-4 and col-lg-4 not working at IE8?

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to develop a responsive template using bootstrap3. It is show perfect result for all major browser except IE8. I have created 3 col in a row. But in desktop for IE8 it is only show 1 col in 1 row . That means IE8 shows tab or mobile version on desktop. I have used html5sive.js and respond.js in head section. I have also run bootstrap jumborton example. But the same result.  This is the code that is not showing correctly-

#### Featured Products

```
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4 ">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product-img ">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/show1.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="row product-description">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-padding ">
                        <img class="product-logo" src="img/show1-icon.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-padding col-left-padding">
                        <h4>Stylish Brown Leather Shoes</h4>
                        <p><strong>$599</strong></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 col-padding">
                        <a href=""><img class="basket" src="img/show-busket.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-lg-4 col-md-4  ">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/show2.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="row product-description">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-padding ">
                        <img class="product-logo" src="img/show2-icon.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-padding col-left-padding">
                        <h4>Elegant Green Wonderful Shoes</h4>
                        <p><strong>$599</strong></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 col-padding">
                        <a href=""><img class="basket" src="img/show-busket.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12 col-md-4  col-lg-4 ">
            <div class="product">
                <div class="product-img">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="img/show3.png" alt="" />
                </div>
                <div class="row product-description">
                    <div class="col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1 col-padding ">
                        <img class="product-logo" src="img/show3-icon.png" alt="" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12 col-padding col-left-padding">
                        <h4>Women Cream and Beautiful Shoes</h4>
                        <p><strong>$599</strong></p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12 col-padding ">
                        <a href=""><img class="basket" src="img/show-busket.png" alt="" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  

        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 issue with Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17947182/ie8-issue-with-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: keep trying. It should work. Do you use cdn versions? Try local versions. You got the mobile version cause the media queries provide by respond.js won't work / load. You will see the mobile first version in ie8

Comment: i have used local version . You can check it here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/168659703/Heavenly/index.html

Comment: got the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127040/respond-js-not-working-in-ie-8 and thanks to Peter_B

Answer (score 2):

Im not fan of ie but it seems you have to use the [ua-compatible](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,IE=EmulateIE8,IE=7,IE=EmulateIE7" />
```