# IE special stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage (to be exact: a game) and it works differently on `IE` and other browsers.
I googled for this and it still doesn't work.

```
<!--[if IE ]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type"text/css" href="iestyle.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Then I tried adding

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

and still nothing.

This is a coding issue, isn't it...?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is correct but from internet explorer 10 [0] on, conditional comments have been removed, that's why you are not seeing the expected behaviour.

[0] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I am using IE 11 if that matters

Comment: Exactly, then look into the link, it explains that from version 10 conditional comments are disregarded. Your syntax is correct, but IE >  9 does not honor it anymore

Answer (score 1):

More details can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/).

**Target ALL VERSIONS of IE**

```
 <!--[if IE]>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
 <![endif]-->
```

**Target everything EXCEPT IE**

```
 <!--[if !IE]><!-->
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 7 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 7]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 6 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 6]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 5 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 5]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie5.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 5.5 ONLY**

```
<!--[if IE 5.5000]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie55.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 6 and LOWER**

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 7 and LOWER**

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 7]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 8 and LOWER**

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 8]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 6 and HIGHER**

```
<!--[if gt IE 5.5]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 6]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 7 and HIGHER**

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 7]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

**Target IE 8 and HIGHER**

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if gte IE 8]>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: you mean one comment for each version?

Comment: No here are the different possibilities. Different IE browsers behave differently. And sometimes you will need a IE per each version. That is up to you.

Comment: Conditional comments have been deprecated and removed since Internet Explorer 10.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of IE - conditional comments are no longer supported.  You can see the answer to a similar question here:

[Why doesn't Internet Explorer 11 honour conditional comments even when emulating Internet Explorer 8 document mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446584/why-doesnt-ie11-honour-conditional-comments-even-when-emulating-ie8-document-mo/19772682#19772682)

I use Modernizr to solve this with feature detection:

```
Modernizr.load({
            test: Modernizr.canvas,
            nope: ['Content/Site-ie-8.min.css', 'Content/font-awesome-ie7.min.css']

        });
```

you can read more about Modernizr here:  http://modernizr.com

Answer (score 0):

Try a `lt` sign as such

```
[if lt IE 10 ]
```

IE 10 and above behave more like other browsers.