# how to keep conditional CSS statements for internet explorer in Express (Node.js) template

Tags: html, css, node.js, internet-explorer, express

I am trying to put conditional statements for internet explorer in my EJS template. It remains as comment in my ejs file. I tried below 2 approaches.

```
<!-- [if gte IE 8 ]>
<style>
    .cs-fixed-header-table {
        height: 500px;
    }
</style> 
<![endif] -->
```

AND

```
<!--[if gte IE 8 ]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="IEstyle.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Anyone of these does not work. What can be done to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just to be sure; does the conditional comments get through to the source of whats returned from the node server?

Comment: @EmilIngerslev yes. it does get through.

Comment: Alright, then its nothing to do with either templating or server, but its simply a browser problem. How do you test the problem?

Comment: When I add a comment described above specifically for Internet exporer in my *.ejs file, then CSS class does not seem applied.

Comment: which version of Internet Explorer are you running?

Comment: @EmilIngerslev  it is IE 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditional comments are not supported by newer versions (IE10+) of Internet Explorer, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx).

So if you really want to handle IE10 or IE11 differently then I'd recommend you do it either through different responses handled by the server or using javascript on the client.

Comment: hey thanks man....it gave a way to go on. I tried media query mentioned at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446584/why-doesnt-internet-explorer-11-honour-conditional-comments-even-when-emulating and it worked. Do Check the answer given by cmartin.

Comment: Oh yeah of cause media queries could also be used :) And glad I could help.