# Why does the IE 11 patch (KB3154070) get targeted by css code as lower than IE10?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have a webpage login which is not compatible with outdated browsers and I have alerted my users of that by using the following:

**CSS**

```
#noIE
{
    display:none\9;
}
.ie10 .myContainer
{
    display:block;
}
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    #disCompatible { display:block !important; }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="lblwar">
    <!--[if lte IE 10]>
        <p class="myalert alert-info">It seems you are using an outdated browser that is 
         no longer supported. Please upgrade your version of Internet Explorer or access
         this site from chrome, firefox or a smart mobile device.</p>
    <![endif]-->
</div>
<div class="myContainer ie10" id="disCompatible">  
    <!-- content that gets hidden from incompatible browsers -->
</div>
```

The issue that I am having is that with the security update for IE11 `KB31540707` the message displays and when tested the page/site shows several jquery and css issues as if it were IE 10 and less. However, if I have IE11 patch `KB3148198` installed the site functions perfectly. How can I resolve the issue that I am having?

Comment: is compatibility mode turned on in any case?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20208018/472134

Comment: @ClydeLobo once again its not only the css code that has an issue with that security patch. Several javascript elements are not functional as well as if it were using an outdated version of IE.

Comment: @DanielA.White that was the resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like compatibility mode. Ensure they are all set the same when running your tests.

Comment: I think you are right. There is an AD(active directory) policy that was forcing PCs to view the page in compatibility mode.