# How to make HTML5 work on Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I made a website with HMTL5, CSS3 and JavaScript. It works on Chrome and Spark but it doesn't work with a CSS file on Internet Explorer.

```
<!--[if IE]-->
<script src="http:html5shim.googlecode.com/suv/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif-]-->
```

I did try other ways, but all of them fail.

Comment: Which version of IE, which HTML, which CSS? The example you show doesn't demonstrate your problem Also, it's malformed, and if it were written correctly, it wouldn't do anything in IE11, which doesn't have conditional comments.

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Well, the url in die `src`of your script tag definitely is not valid...

Comment: @MrLister http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19446584/why-doesnt-internet-explorer-11-honour-conditional-comments-even-when-emulating

Comment: @QueryLars It can be. "html5shim.googlecode.com" can be a subdirectory!

Comment: @MrLister If you insist that this is a valid url try opening it in your browser.

Comment: @QueryLars I did. I made a subdirectory under my localhost with that name and it worked fine.

Comment: I need it work in all of IE  version

Comment: @MrLister Ah I see. Sorry... But I am 100% sure this is not what OP is intending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please format `src` attribute value properly like this.

```
<script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okey thank you i will try it

Comment: If your edit is rejected, do not make it again. There's a reason it was rejected.