# Twitter-Bootstrap respond.js not working for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8

I'm still having some problems getting my Twitter-Bootstrap page to display the desktop view correctly in IE8. I've been following a few threads here but the voted up advice is just not working for me.

Using the suggested meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Included local versions of bootstrap.css, html5shiv.js, respond.js, ie8-responsive-file-warning.js

Here is my head section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="SunTrust Equity Line Options">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

<title>SunTrust &ndash; Your Equity Line is Maturing. What are your options?</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="dis/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->

<!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="dist/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="dist/js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

And the end of it:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/tooltip.js"></script>
<script src="dist/js/popover.js"></script>
<script>
$("a[rel=popover]")
    .popover()
    .click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
     });
 </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127040/respond-js-not-working-in-ie-8 it will help you

Comment: @2dar That answer doesn't seem to apply to this code.

Comment: I've reviewed the stackoverflow thread suggested above. None of the items listed there seems to help it.

Comment: Are you running this locally or from a server? respond.js will only work in the latter case. See https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond#support--caveats

Comment: I am running it on a server not locally. You can view it here (http://bit.ly/1j1AW4i)

Answer (score 8):

Try using local copy of bootstrap. This solved my problem with IE8.

Comment: you're welcome. The reason why you need a local copy of bootstrap is because  respond.js cannot parse remote css asset.

Answer (score 2):

Well I've asked several people and read a ton on this and still no answer on this. Seems like the only way to fix it is to call an IE8 only style sheet to get things to display correctly.

Event the getbootstrap.com examples don't work in IE8 they all stack the same way mobile first in IE8.

It's a shame really since I won't be able to use it for most projects.

Comment: That suggests there's an issue with your install of IE8. All of the examples work in IE8 for me.

Comment: You're saying you see the 3 column items, the ones with the titles and buttons, in a row next to each other in IE8? Not stacked on of each other? I still see them stacked which is not what I want. The getbootstrap.com examples have 3 column items stacked as well.

Comment: Yes, e.g. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/ and http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/ work correctly.

Comment: Not sure this is a IE8 install issue. I am using IE11 and emulating IE8 with the Document Mode set to 8 and the User Agent String set to IE8 and I have the same issue @TerriSwiatek does. When I view the Jumbotron bootstrap link it doesn't show 3 columns but instead the elements are stacked on top of each other.

Answer (score 2):

Always make sure that you load the following scripts *after* loading jQuery.

Especially in WordPress and other frameworks some people tend to include jQuery just before the closing  tag and therefore after the html5shiv.js and respond.js script, which causes issues in IE8

```
<!-- Include first -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
  <script src="js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 1):

i see you are using "dis/js/..." in one place and "dist/js/" in other places. Are you sure your paths are correct? I would double check the browser is actually loading the files you think its loading.

or it could be the duplication of conditional comments, try this for grins: (of course fix the paths in the below code too if "dis" or "dist" is incorrect)

```
<!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy this line! -->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="dis/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="dist/js/respond.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

I'm also not familiar with ie8-responsive-file-warning.js, i would try removing that if all else fails to be sure its not conflicting with respond.js.  For that matter remove html5shiv as well just to rule out all conflicts.

Comment: dist/js/html5shiv.js and dist/js/respond.js are the correct directories. I've checked the full paths in the browser and it pulls up the files contents. I removed the ie8-responsive-file-warning.js as suggested but still getting the same results. (http://skmgroupwork.com/suntrust/email/stac307b/indexhover.html)

Answer (score 0):

We discovered that having css links outside of the "head" section (essentially that for the bootstrap css) broke respond.js's ability to provide the necessary media query support as required. Ensure that all your css links live within your "head" section.