# External CSS in Internet Explorer 11 not working

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

I am doing some basic editing to change my font color using the external css. When I open in IE11 the font color didn't work and it change to normal black text color.

However when I open in the Mozilla firefox, the font color turns red which is what I expected.

Has anyone encountered a similar situation as me?

Here are my basic code in the external css:

```
p.marking {
    /* color: #376092; */
    color:#FF0000;
    font: bold 24px "Arial", sans-serif;
    position:relative; z-index:1;
}
```

I changed from blue to red for the font color. Only Firefox can be shown. IE 11 turns the text to default black text color.

Comment: Have you tried `shift` + `F5`? (on the webpage) For that matter `CRL` + `F5` = cache refresh.

Comment: @Ruddy the crl+F5 works. But why does every color I changed in the css will not changed upon the first browsing. I have to do the control + F5 to refresh. Is there a way to make it show on the first time browsing?

Comment: **[What is a browser's cache](http://www.pctools.com/security-news/what-is-a-browser-cache/)**

Comment: @gonggong It could be in the browser settings. As someone just put a link to explain it go have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As we now know its due to the browser caching the site.

**In short:** It saves the CSS/HTML pages so you don't have to get it again.

I recommend the same link as Patsy said: [READ ABOUT BROWSER CACHE](http://www.pctools.com/security-news/what-is-a-browser-cache/)

So to get past this problem we can tell the bowser to get the HTML/CSS again using:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

**What it says on that page:**

> A cache is a repository for stored data that is used to expedite the
> process of retrieving data. There are several types of caches,
> including webpage caches, hardware caches, software caches and memory
> caches. Caches are used to speed up a process so that data does not
> have to be recomputed or fetched from its original location and,
> therefore, saves time. The greater the requests that can be served
> from the cache, the quicker system performance becomes. A cache hit is
> when a program checks the cache for previously stored information and
> finds it. A cache miss is when the data is not found within the cache
> and the program must look to a larger, slower memory source. Computers
> can have several caches: the L1 cache is built into the computer
> processor’s chip, the L2 cache is built onto the motherboard and the
> L3 cache is just the L2 cache on a computer that has two caches built
> into the microprocessor.
>
> Internet browsers use caching to store HTML
> web pages by storing a copy of visited pages and then using that copy
> to render when you re-visit that page. If the date on the page is the
> same date as the previously stored copy, then the computer uses the
> one on your hard drive rather than re-downloading it from the
> internet.

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot. Even if so, isn't that a bug for IE11? Since other web browser like Firefox, I do not have to clear the cache at all after editing my font color in css and it can still be shown after editing. Unlike IE.

Comment: Erm, maybe? I guess they have something in place to tell if there is a newer file ready for download. Other then that maybe its a setting somewhere you can turn on and off?

Comment: So far I cant find any to turn on or off. It just make tester frustrated when its just a basic change in css and the color wont change. Misleading tester thinking there might be other problems. Oh well haha, thanks a lot guys!

Comment: I will have a little look around later, if I find anything I will report back! If you feel this is the answer can you accept it? It could also help other people.

Comment: Hi ruddy, haha..I am just trying my luck by asking..Is there by any chance I can get your opinion about Marking algorithm?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question but what do you mean "Marking algorithm"?

Comment: Ok I am currently working on a project. Mathematics Online assessment. As you know some students may do their working steps shorter than the solution steps. I want to mark the workings line by line. I already had an algorithm but the accuracy may not be as high depending on the question and solution and student working. I would think of it as an AI job but just asking for your opinion what you think about this about the accuracy part.

Comment: Im not sure tbh, not my kinda of thing. Sorry about that but is an algorithm really the best way to go for that sort of thing? There are so many options to solve a single problem, things that even you didn't think of. Potentially you will be giving less credit to the people that should be getting more? (I hope that made some sense, I think I understood what you was saying).

Answer (score 1):

IE [supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906794/internet-explorers-css-rules-limits) only 4095 css selectors in the file. It's infrequent case, but may be this is it?

Comment: Hmm I do not get what you mean? Maybe you care to explain further?

Comment: They mean you can only have 4095 rules in a CSS file. e.g: `table { border: 1px solid; }` = 1

Comment: I see..that helps a lot. Just an opinion after my encounter, IE is so troublesome? It makes testing so much worst.