# To handle IE9, I need to have Meteor NOT concatenate the css files

Tags: meteor

IE9 has a 4095 selectors / stylesheet limit. ( [you can read a little bit about that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906794/internet-explorers-css-rules-limits) ). Once that limit is hit, the rest of the styling rules are silently ignored. (thank you Microsoft employees for not even bothering with a error message to console)

I would a clean solution from the Meteor community on how to have Meteor serve the original css files (minimizing is o.k. but not concatenated) to IE9-.

We are doing a temporary hack of asking user to upgrade but that seems really lame since the solution is "simply" get Meteor to not concatenate the css files.

Comment: there is no such a way yet. It would be nice to open a GitHub issue to track this though :)

Comment: I think the better way would be to ask user to use a normal browser instead of upgrading IE ;)

Comment: IE jokes aside, if you haven't already open a GitHub issue on Meteor's page.

Comment: @imslavko - github issue: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1876

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps in your case, but we faced a similar issue with IE earlier and the workaround we used was to split the CSS generated into multiple files. IE allows upto 31 stylesheets per page so that makes up to 4095 x 31 selectors, which is better but still not the best.

Comment: meteor concatenates the css

Comment: for now u should consider putting part of your css in /public and reference it manually.

Comment: Our solution: "we defined away the problem": we decided not to support IE9 :-)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you should split, minify, and concatenate the CSS yourself, and place it inside the `/public` directory and reference it that way.