# CSS broken after concating together in IE 9

Tags: css

I am using yui-compressor.jar to contact all my css files together. This works fine on all browsers except IE 9

This is how I am contacting:

```
exec ('cat '.implode($css_files, ' ').' | java -jar yuicompressor.jar --type css -o ../css/all.css');
```

What would I have to look for to figure out why this is happening. There must be an error in a css file somewhere, but I don't know what to look for.

This is NOT happen in IE 10, 11 or any other browser.

Comment: implode is backwards, implode(' ',$css_files)

Comment: It is backwords, but php.net says it can go in either order.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at that IE 9 has a selector limit per file as discussed here:

[Internet Explorer's CSS rules limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906794/internet-explorers-css-rules-limits)

Answer (score 0):

Internet Explorer 6 through 9 has a CSS selector limit of 4095 selectors.

To avoid this, simply split your CSS files into the minimum number needed to avoid this issue and fall below the limit.

You can find more information here on how to split your CSS files using BlessCSS: http://www.dannetherton.co.uk/blog/2015/02/solution-for-the-internet-explorer-css-selector-limit-bug/