# Website partly loads CSS in IE8-IE9

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, modernizr, html5shiv

I can't seem to fix the following website for IE9:

http://www.allyum.com

I've implemented Modernizr and Html5Shiv but nothing seems to work. If you test it in other browsers everything works perfectly fine. Does anyone have an idea what the issue can be here?

Comment: "Debug my web site" questions with only a link to the site are likely to be closed. To avoid it, you should create a minimal but complete example that shows the problem and paste the code in the question. See also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Comment: And what do you want me to post, the entire code of the website? I have no idea where my problem lies. If we get that figured out I am gladly to post all the code you want.

Comment: @WarreBuysse `nothing seems to work` / `I have no idea where my problem lies.` Spend some time debugging! Once you've found a *specific*, programming-related issue, head on back.

Comment: Are you running into a **[rules limit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906794/internet-explorers-css-rules-limits)**

Comment: I know the feeling. Getting modern websites to play nice in IE8/9 is a major PITA. The issue appears to be with Bootstrap, have you seen this tutorial? http://www.joostrap.com/blog/bootstrap-3-supporting-internet-explorer-8-and-9

Comment: @WarreBuysse No judgement! Debugging is a great and learned skill, one that you will find very useful if you continue professional development. Good luck!

Comment: &adrndrew It's not about being able to debug something or not. It's being focused on one thing while it's something else. A clear view from someone else often fixes the problem or gives you a new view on the problems. I'm perfectly able of debugging, but if I get stuck on something stupid I'd rather ask for help than kill my entire evening.

Comment: @WarreBuysse: the comments above on this old question were quite correct for a reason that was not explicitly stated. The problem of link-only questions is that once the issue is fixed, new readers cannot view the problem for themselves. This is why we ask that the problem is reproduced in a JS Fiddle as well as in code samples here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site enters Quirks mode in IE9. 
Add this to LINE 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

You have this line but it is in comments and on line 2. IE wants it on line 1.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I was totally focussing on Modernizr issues or something of the kind. You just saved a life.