# Full layout recomputing on mouse hover with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am troubleshooting performance issues on IE 11 with an existing HTML page which is quite big (table with a few hundred rows containing links).

I noticed with the F12 UI responsiveness tool that the lagging is caused by many "Layout" events generated as soon as I move the mouse anywhere hover the page and which basically recompute the style of all elements (including the table cells) even if the mouse is on the page's header section.

From the documentation:

> •Layout: Changes were made to the DOM that required the size and/or position of all affected elements to be computed.

How can I find the cause of this issue?

I guess there is some `:hover` CSS style somewhere that causes this full style recomputing, but how to find out which one?

Comment: put your css code here

Comment: unfortunately there is far too much CSS across several different files, that's why I'm looking for a way to identify the suspect from the F12 tools.

Comment: if the problem is in your css you can:
· Go to elements tab
· Select html or body element
· Click on ":a" symbol
· Check "Mantener el mouse" (in spanish)
· And see if any styles are added to the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems that the performance issue was caused by the excessive number of CSS rules which  was beyond the limit described here: [Internet Explorer's CSS rules limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906794/internet-explorers-css-rules-limits)