# CSS compressed doesn't load in IE9, with Bootstrap 3.1

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-9

I'm trying to load a compressed set of files  .Css on a page, but in IE9 only loads a part of them. In other browsers and IE10-11 load correctly.

The code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

   <?php
      foreach($view->_css as $css){
       echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$css.'">'."\n";  //loads all .css compressed
        }
        foreach($view->_js as $js){
           echo '<script src="'.$js.'"></script>'."\n";  //loads all .js
        }
        ?>
        <title>Test</title> ...
```

The file .css are: bootstrap.css , ace.css and other, but only work bootstrap.css. Someone know a fix? thanks

Comment: Can you share your array being returned as $view->_css?

Comment: Sure. 
     [_css] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://192.168.0.61/test/ec77744fa9a76363c2564a80007c64b7.css
        )

    [_js] => Array
        (
            [0] => http://192.168.0.61/test/5132b174c4bc7a8d6c7c4509e6f17225.js
        )

Comment: Have you checked the MIME type of the stylesheet a and javascript? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/03/27/http-406-not-acceptable-php-ie9-standards-mode-accepts-only-text_2f00_css-for-stylesheets.aspx

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that you are running into [Internet Explorer's CSS rules limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906794/internet-explorers-css-rules-limits) for IE9, which would explain why it effects IE9, but not later versions. If that is the case, you would want to split up your CSS files for IE9.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your attention and help. @James, You are right.. The problem was just that there is a limit in relation to the IE9 css: 
[link] blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/10164546.aspx [/link]
The solution was a small implementation, our framework to split the css file when loaded in IE9 and pass the bounds of it.