# IE 9 ignores CSS when under selector limit

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've got [this stylesheet](http://bi-staging.biginterview.netdna-cdn.com/assets/application-a664cd35602e8e91233c170ee1e3b3b1.css) and `IE <= 9` is ignoring almost all of the styles in it.

Actually, the point in [the stylesheet](http://bi-staging.biginterview.netdna-cdn.com/assets/application-a664cd35602e8e91233c170ee1e3b3b1.css) at which IE starts to ignore the additional selectors is `#user_show .settings-container h1`, which, if you look at the source, is only about 3/4 of the way through the CSS.

I assumed that this was a [selector limit thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906794/internet-explorers-css-rules-limits), but can't seem to verify that:

Using the following sites/scripts I get these results:

- [Online Counter](http://snippet.bevey.com/css/selectorCount.php): **2865 selectors**
- [Console Script](https://gist.github.com/psebborn/1885511): **3639 selectors**

If my calculations are correct, these appear to be under the 4096 limit even though IE sure is acting like I've hit it. I'm assuming counting selectors can be wildly different (see results), but I'm not sure why those tools are not reporting anywhere close to the limit even though it seems I'm hitting it.

Is there anything else that could be going?

Comment: Did you try to move that selector to the top of your stylesheet to see if that is effecting the result?  Might want to rule out the selector first.

Comment: Can you show us the site you are observing this on?