# Ckeditor throwing error 'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.'

Tags: internet-explorer, ckeditor, internet-explorer-9, wysiwyg, fckeditor

I've couple of custom ckeditor plugin which loading custom css files for there own styling.
I'm adding custom style sheet using following code,

```
cssStyles.push("/css/custom.css");
```

Its working fine with CKeditor 3.6, but after upgrading ckeditor from 3.6 to 4.4.1, in IE-9 & IE -8 its throwing following error,
'Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.'
As per my investigation I've found that IE can't load more than 30 files, so I modified my code like,

```
editor.addContentsCss && editor.addContentsCss( CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath( '/css/custom.css' );
```

Its working fine in Chrome, even in IE-11, but in IE-09 its throwing an error - 'invalid argument'.

So is there any way to aggregate all css files or any plugin/patch to get rid of?

Answer (score 1):

How did you add the extra plugins? The recommended way of adding additional plugins to CKEditor is using the [online builder](http://ckeditor.com/builder). If you have your own plugins, then the [command line builder](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_build) will be handy. The builder will take care of merging files and producing a build with minimal number of files.

Comment: I've never seen problems with a maximum number of files when using a dev version which loads perhaps far more.

Comment: True, but you were probably not enabling 3rd party plugins which unlike most "official" CKEditor plugins could provide additional CSS files resulting in some weird IE problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906794/internet-explorers-css-rules-limits. Then using the builder to reduce the number of CSS files/imports/whatever provided by CKEditor skins may make the difference. I might be wrong ofc.

Comment: Hmm... you may be right. I was more thinking about files in general, not only CSS files.

Answer (score 0):

Due to following IE9 rules I was getting the error:

- A sheet may contain up to 4095 selectors
- A sheet may import up to 31 sheets
- Import nesting supports up to 4 levels deep

Referring to [Stylesheet Limits in IE](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/10164546.aspx).