# JavaScript runtime error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, performance, asp.net-web-api

I have four service call functions for dropdown binding in a screen, am using `angularjs` `http` call for get data from `WEB API` service.

below are the methods

```
 function loadProjects() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: rootUrl + '/api/Project/ProjectList',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }
            }).success(function (response) {
                response.push({ ProjectName: "Select", ProjectId: 0 });
                $scope.ProjectList = response;
                $scope.SelectedProject = response[$scope.ProjectList.length - 1];
            }).error(function (response, errorCode) {
                if (errorCode == 444) {
                    //toastr.error('Your email address is does not verrified ', 'Error');
                }
            })
        }
        function loadTasks() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: rootUrl + '/api/Task/TaskList',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }
            }).success(function (response) {
                $scope.TaskList = response;
            }).error(function (response, errorCode) {
                if (errorCode == 444) {
                    //toastr.error('Your email address is does not verrified ', 'Error');
                }
            })
        }
        function loadStatus() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: rootUrl + '/api/Status/GetAllStatus',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }
            }).success(function (response) {
                response.push({ StatusTypeName: "Select", StatusTypeId: 0 });
                $scope.StatusType = response;
                $scope.SelectedStatusType = response[$scope.StatusType.length - 1];
            }).error(function (response, errorCode) {
                if (errorCode == 444) {
                    //toastr.error('Your email address is does not verrified ', 'Error');
                }
            })
        }
        function loadUserList() {
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: rootUrl + '/api/Account/ListOfUsers',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }
            }).success(function (response) {
                response.push({ FirstName: "Select", UserId: 0 });
                $scope.UserList = response;
                $scope.SelectedUser = response[$scope.UserList.length - 1];
            }).error(function (response, errorCode) {
                if (errorCode == 444) {
                    //toastr.error('Your email address is does not verrified ', 'Error');
                }
            })
        }
```

I have call the above functions in one by one.

```
loadUserList();
loadProjects();
loadStatus();
loadTasks();
```

**Html :** `I have binding the four dropdown by this way`

```
<select style="width: 160px" ng-model="SelectedTask" class="form-control" name="SelectedTask"
                        ng-options="tasklist.TaskName for tasklist in  TaskList">
                    </select>
```

This first two functions are  very slow for get some data from `WEBAPI`, my database have just 5 rows only. but very slow. but i am using same functions in another screen, that's working very good.

also i got this error message whenever the `loadStatus();` *(third function)* function is calling.

The error message is : *JavaScript runtime error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation. in angularjs*

And also i will show the performance details when i run some other screens vs the problem detected screen.

[image]

See the `CPU` usage. I can't find out the solution. Please help me.

> I also got some answers from google, but they said it is a visual studio problem. but I don't think this is vs problem. because other screens are working well. Please help me guys ;) Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your javascript error only in IE?

Comment: Yes, i got this error only in IE. Other browser does not show any error. But   i got performance issues only.

Comment: Hm, k. Have you tried inspecting what the responses are in your ajax calls? I'd just want to verify that you're not pulling in something you don't want to. For example, an ORM might unexpectedly pull in joined tables and you end up with a giant model object instead of a small row like you expect.

Comment: Also, have you tried making the ajax calls synchronous (not ideal, but for debugging). Put the next call in the success callback of each one and see if it's angular that's getting slammed because all of your ajax calls are returning at once.  It should be able to handle this...and much more though... Just an idea.

Comment: Similar issues:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405826/internet-explorer-11-not-enough-storage-error
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979073/not-enough-storage-is-available-to-complete-this-operation
https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/Feedback/Details/1053110

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve a problem with the same error by going into IE's Internet Options > Browsing History Settings > Disk Space. Increase the disk space allowed and this may solve your problem.

It turns out IE by default only allows 250MB disk space to be used by the browser. Of course this is only an environmental change specific to one machine, but this worked in my case (as we used data > 250 MB)